# After renaming a type, I cannot access some of its methods

Tags: methods, types, go

In order to prevent having multiple dependencies along different files of my project and since I might change how data will be presented, I decided to make an "interface" (not in the golang sense but in an architectural way) to the [draw2d package](https://github.com/llgcode/draw2d)

As I didn't need anything else, I just renamed one of the types:

```
type CanvasContext draw2dimg.GraphicContext
```

In one of my modules I had the following code (path is a CanvasContext variable):

```
// initialization and some code omitted for clarity
path.SetFillColor(color.RGBA{0x44, 0xff, 0x44, 0xff})
path.SetStrokeColor(color.RGBA{0x44, 0x44, 0x44, 0xff})
path.SetLineWidth(5)
// some more code here
path.Close()
path.FillStroke()
```

Among all those method calls on path, only the FillStroke failed with the compile error:

> path.FillStroke undefined (type *drawing.CanvasContext has no field or
>   method FillStroke)

In order to prevent it I have to redefine the FillStroke, but not any other method, with:

```
func (cc *CanvasContext) FillStroke() {
    gc := draw2dimg.GraphicContext(*cc)
    gc.FillStroke()
}
```

Why do I have to redefine only that one and not any of the other calls?

Comment: The `draw2dimg` package defines type `GraphicContext` as embedding another type that implements most of those methods. However, the `FillStroke` method is implemented directly on `GraphicContext` only. If you use embedding it will work as you seem to expect, if not it won't. See [this simplified example](https://play.golang.org/p/mvRCew6UpC). (I.e. `type Foo Bar` does ***not*** make `Bar`'s methods available, use embedding for that).

Comment: while I still don't know the reason behind that decission, I can see by your example what is wrong in my code.
If you answer the question (instead of commenting) I'll mark your answer as valid :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use struct embedding rather than type define. check the struct '[embedding](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding)' document:

> but then to promote the methods of the fields and to satisfy the io
>   interfaces, we would also need to provide forwarding methods, like
>   this:
>
> func (rw *ReadWriter) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
>          return rw.reader.Read(p)    }
>
> By embedding the structs directly, we avoid this bookkeeping.