# Executing actual object method from inherited struct without cast type to inherited type

Tags: inheritance, go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type IA interface {
    Parse()
    Name() string
}

type A struct {
    IA
}

func (a *A) Name() string {
    return "AName"
}

func (a *A) Parse() {
    fmt.Println("A-" + a.Name())
}

type B struct {
    A
}

func (b *B) Name() string {
    return "BName"
}


func main() {
    a := &A{}
    b := &B{}

    a.Parse()
    b.Parse() // I would like to see "A-BName"
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Z2hSBoakKHy)

When I execute method from inherited struct with execute another struct method in it - is executed method from inherited struct, not actual object type.

Comment: There is no "inheritance" in go, simply composition with some syntactic sugar on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JimB said, there is no proper inheritance in Go as in other languages. To help visualize this, let's take your code in `main()`:

```
a := &A{}
b := &B{}

a.Parse()
b.Parse()
```

When `a.Parse()` is called, the Go compiler checks if `a` has a method `Parse()`, and it does. So it calls the method `a.Parse`.

When `b.Parse()` is called, the Go compiler checks if `b` has a method `Parse()`, and it does not - but an embedded field inside the struct does! So it simply uses the method from that field, and thus `b.A.Parse()` is called. In fact, you could change B to this:

```
type B struct {
    A A
}
```

And the only difference would be that `b.Parse()` wouldn't work and that you'd have to specify `.A` manually (thus `b.A.Parse()`), but it remains functionally the same.

---

Further reading:

- [Golang and inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32188653/5328069)
- [Effective Go - Embedding](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding)